# How to export & import custom helpers in JS/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging, console.log

**Task :**

- So, I'd rather not type **`console`** each time I want to use it. 
  I want to import some shorthand, eg--

  **`log('hi')`** same as **`console.log('hi')`**

**Tried Case :**

- Here is my work so far. 
  I'd like to use shorthand of **`log, warn, error, info`** to corresponding console functions.
- I hope this doesn't seem totally bad practice, but I'm willing to listen.

**Problem :**

- I'm puzzled how to export and import these in order to use the
  desired notation.

Open to all suggestions.
Please suggest.
Thank you.

```
log = (arg, ...argv) => console.log(arg, ...argv)
err = (arg, ...argv) => console.error(arg, ...argv)
error = (arg, ...argv) => console.error(arg, ...argv)
info = (arg, ...argv) => console.info(arg, ...argv)
warn = (arg, ...argv) => console.warn(arg, ...argv)

// how to export? should this be a class?
```

Comment: You could have just use destructuring: `let { log, err, info, warn } = console`

Comment: Oh that's awesome. Can you export those from a file? I will mark correct answer for above at any rate.

Comment: You could, but you'd end up with the exact same code. So just use that code and forget about making it a module.

Comment: @MinusFour `err` not belongs to console, am i correct?

Comment: correct, i just want the shorthand `err` : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can shorthand.

Create a file ex : `log.js` with below functions.

```
export const log = (arg, ...argv) => {
    console.log(arg, ...argv)
}
export const err  = (arg, ...argv) => {
  console.error(arg, ...argv)
} 
export const error   = (arg, ...argv) => {
   console.error(arg, ...argv)
}

export const info   = (arg, ...argv) => {
  console.info(arg, ...argv)
}

export const warn   = (arg, ...argv) => {
   console.warn(arg, ...argv)
}
```

Later you just import these functions in other component where you want to use.

```
import {log, err, error, info, warn} from './log'; //path may be different
```

Then just call functions wherever you want.

```
log('hi', [1,2,3]);
err('hi', [1,2,3]);
error('hi', [1,2,3]);
info('hi', [1,2,3]);
warn('hi', [1,2,3]);
```

Comment: is there a way to get these functions with a simpler `import './helpers/console'` statement?

Comment: yeah you can do with `import * as util from './log';` but again you have to call functions like `util.log('hi', [1,2,3]);`, again its like calling `console.log('hi', [1,2,3]);`

Comment: I thought there might be a way to import them without casting/destructuring-- all at once.

Comment: i don't think which supports other than the above way which i mentioned in comment, yeah you can refer here for different ways of importing -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: @tidelake got any best answers ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm sorry, I recall marking your answer correct.

Answer (score 1):

General keyword to export function in ES6 is **export** (custom export function file)

```
export const functionName = (arg, ...argv) => {
   console.log(arg, ...argv)
}
```

General keyword to import function in ES6 is **import** (custom import function file)

```
import { functionName } from './export_function_file';
```